# TextView with a background and Transparent Text

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to do the following:

[image]

For now, I am trying to use NativeAndroid.

However, I can do this with **HTML and css.**

As you can see, it's something like:

- Holder with blue (might be any other color or even an IMAGE) background
- TextView with (transparent??) color
- TextView with gray background

However, if I set background to grey and the text to transparent, the text "disappears" and it's all shown as gray.

This is my try (Native Android):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffcecece"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#00ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, it's showing the following:

[image]

There's text, bu as it is transparent, it's not shown.

So my question is:

- How can I achieve this?
- Canvas? Spans? I'm not used to those approach, so some directions would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Edit:
**That blue background must be dynamic and it may be an IMAGE!**

Comment: Will you have dynamic background? If not just set text color to background color.

Comment: The background is most probably an image... So, it's otally dynamic

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check the edit comment.

Comment: @Reinherd: you are looking exactly for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24281113/913286) of mine.

Comment: @GilVegliach I was* 3 years ago :D

Comment: @Reinherd: you're right :D Anyway, it will be a good reference for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Canvas for that:

```
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(1200, 1200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//bMap.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
Paint paint = new Paint();

Paint mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mPaintText.setStrokeWidth(3);
mPaintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
mPaintText.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaintText.setTextSize(50f);
mPaintText.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));    
canvas.drawText("Your TExt", x, y, mPaintText);
```

Comment: I'm not used in using canvas. How can I add this code as a View?

Comment: you can add an ImageView to your layout and then: ImageView image = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);image.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);

Comment: I've tried that and the text, if it's transparent it's invisible, so it's not working.

Comment: try this: http://android.okhelp.cz/create-bitmap-and-draw-text-into-bitmap-android-example/

Comment: This is what I do need. However I tried to use it in my app (copy & paste) and the text is not transparent. Can you try it?

Comment: Okay, it worked with this:            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));

Answer (score 1):

Set the `textcolor` as your layout `backgound` color like light sky blue..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this in Xml Layout, you need to set same color for both layout background and the text like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0011ff" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffcecece"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#0011ff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not what I need. Check my Edit.

Comment: You can do that in your java class where you want by setting the backgroundResource as follows:  mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagename);

Comment: It's not about the image. It's about setting the text transparent, so you can read "through" the TextView

Comment: You don't understand what I am trying to do. Check the question again please.